# Flutter Caching Very Old Errors

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, flutter

## 1. The Problem

Usually, either `flutter clean` or deleting `/build` folder works for me. But, recently, some errors have been cached for a long time and I just can't seem to be able to delete them. The cleaning process is also supposedly taking way longer than expected (+3s in my reasonably good computer).

The reason why I say it is caching error logs is that essentially all of it refers to silly typo mistakes I have fixed long ago or other types of easy-to-fix mistakes. For example, 2 days ago (my computer rebooted 2 times since then), I've used an `.email` getter on an object that doesn't have it and the log is still there; or the fact that it is saying that I've used an invalid object on oneline, but now there is bascially nothing in that file anymore.

The app also builds and runs perfectly after these long error messages, and, if I *hot reload* or *hot restart* it, no errors reappear.

I would like to share my complete error log here, but a good part of it has a lot of personal data. It is also not very relevant I think, because it mostly refers to silly mistakes and typos.

## 2. What I've tried so far

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. `flutter clean`
2. Manually delete the `/build` folder
3. Restart my IDE

   - These error messages appear both on `VS Code` (my current IDE) and `Android Studio`.
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + `Clear Editor History` to reset `VS Code`.

Is there some hidden folder within a `Flutter` project that could be caching these data?

Comment: Are you using a simulator?

Comment: Forgot to mention it, but I'm using the Andoid Emulator, as I believe most people do.

Comment: Could those errors be stored in the emulator and not in the `/build` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there is some *linkage between the* `Flutter` *project and the emulator itself*, because **wiping out the emulator's data** seems to have solved the problem.

Was that supposed to happen? I think this should be treated as a `Flutter` issue — more specifically: [`flutter/flutter` #45478 Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45478).

Comment: This issue apparently is coming from the `dev` channel only.